# Is there a difference when using Java Double.parseDouble and the same method in Android?

Tags: java, android

The reason I ask is because I have 2 exact same bits of code in an android app and in a java program doing the same thing (collecting tidal data):

```
String[] string4 = tide4.replaceAll("[LmH]", "").split(" ");
         Time4 = string4[0];
         String height4 = string4[1].replaceAll("\\s", "");

         System.out.println("HEIGHT4 = " + "'" + height4 + "'" );

        //Convert the Meters into feet for tide heights
      double heightM4 = Double.parseDouble(height4); //FAILS ON THIS LINE IN **JAVA** NOT IN ANDROID
```

Exception: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.24 "`

However in the java program running on my machine it fails when parsing it? in Android it carries on fine.
I have noticed one thing different when testing. When printing the value of "height4" in eclipse on my machine it outputs something like this: `HEIGHT4 = '6.24 ' <--Notice the space!`
In Android it outputs this: `HEIGHT4 = '6.24'<--No Space?`
Nothing is different between the 2 bits of code except the platform they are running on( as far as I can see).
What could the cause of this be? Something to do with that un-removable whitespace?

Comment: so what you are saying is that the method behaves differently when given different inputs? apparently either `replaceAll` is actually different, or the content of `tide4` is not the same

Comment: Use "\\s+" and you should be good.

Comment: Hi, there both the same in the Java version and Android I have checked multiple times im sure of it, they are collecting the same data using the same bits of code.

Comment: @JaredRummler have tried that one already, thanks

Comment: What about writing a unit test, and let it run on both plattforms with the exact same input. And yes, android java is not sun java, but hopefully behave the same, but your problem is related to replaceAll, which produce the additional space, not the parseDouble()

Comment: Altough your Problem is not  the parseDouble, I can tell you that IBM Embedded Java J9 (1.3)  implementtaion of parseDouble() cannot parse "Infinity"  while sun java can.

Comment: @AlexWien Hi, thanks for pointing out that it is replaceAll, any ideas why replaceAll isn't replacingAll

Comment: Either different input (maybe LineFeeds in File:  Android is Linux based, while your PC probably is Windows)  or different implementtaion of replaceAll.

Comment: To solve: chnage to this: Double.parseDouble(height4.trim()); That removes spaces.

Comment: Just tried it, sorry didn't work?, still outputs with that space

Comment: @AlexWien and yes my machine is Windows....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could the cause of this be? Something to do with that un-removable whitespace?

I think it is everything to do with that mysterious character.  It is clearly not a digit or one of the other characters that are valid in a number, and that would definitely result in a parse error.

What you need to do is to use a debugger or some trace printing to find out what the mysterious character is.  For example:

```
    char last = height4.charAt(height4.length() - 1); 
    System.out.println("The last character codepoint is " + ((int) last));
```

then convert the codepoint to hexadecimal and look it up in the Unicode tables at http://unicode.org

Once you have done that, you can figure out where the mystery is coming from and / or what is the best way to get rid of it.

---

Advice: If I would you, I would focus on figuring out where the character is coming from.  The fact that you are getting strange stuff is a worry, and points to the potential for other problems.  If you just try to get rid of the bad stuff, then you may be sweeping a larger problem under the carpet; e.g. making it harder to find.

---

**UPDATE** - The `0x00A0` code point is the "non-breaking space" (NBSP) character in the LATIN-1 supplement:

- The `String.trim()` method doesn't remove this.  It only removes ASCII control codes; i.e. `0x0000` through `0x0020`.
- In the regex language implemented by `Pattern`, `"\\s"` doesn't match all Unicode space variants.  This Question has the solution: [Java regular expression to match _all_ whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822772/java-regular-expression-to-match-all-whitespace-characters)

The presence of a NBSP is not as problematic as "random characters", but it suggests that you are "scraping" your input from rendered text (e.g. HTML) and there are differences in the rendering or scraping processes between the two platforms.  While not worrying *per se*, this is something you need to keep in mind.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the helpful answer. The codepoint is 160, which is \u00A0.

Comment: Success, replacing \u00A0 and it now works. Thank you. But, could you offer any reason why &nbsp; doesn't work, i thought it was the same? also why would it be handled differently on Android? it has already been mentioned that Android Java is different from Sun Java so is it down to that? Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the update on the answer, very helpful! especialy for an amature with no teacher, just text! Stillgotahellofalottolearn.